# Angular, how do you detect when an animation finishes?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, animation, angular-animations

I am trying to detect when an animation finishes so that I can execute something afterwards, my research has led me the `@animation.done` and `@animation.start` but it seems to fire in the beginning regardless of if my animation is finished.

I consolelog'd a message in my `@animation.done` function and it fires in the beginning even before the animation happens I believe

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vtuydu?file=src/app/app.component.ts

HTML:

```
<button
  type="button"
  class="button-viewproject"
  [@fadeInUpViewProject]="viewProjectState ? 'in' : 'out'"
  (@fadeInUpViewProject.done)="animationDone($event)"
>
  View Me
</button>
```

TS:

```
  animationDone(event: any) {
    console.log(this.viewProjectState); // alert('hey'); Seems to execute no matter what
    // alert('hey'); Seems to execute no matter what
    setTimeout(() => {}, 1900);
  }
```

Comment: your animation spend 2 seconds, you're saying Angular that change the variable `viewProjectState` (and start the animation) each 555 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [AnimationEvent](https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationEvent) object passed into your `animationDone()` method, you'll see that the method gets called twice: once for going from state `'void'` to state `'out'`, then a second time for going from state `'out'` to state `'in'`:

Call #1 event:

```json
{
  "element": {},
  "triggerName": "fadeInUpViewProject",
  "fromState": "void", <----------------
  "toState": "out", <-------------------
  "phaseName": "done",
  "totalTime": 0,
  "disabled": false,
  "_data": 1
}
```

Call #2 event:

```json
{
  "element": {},
  "triggerName": "fadeInUpViewProject",
  "fromState": "out", <-----------------
  "toState": "in", <--------------------
  "phaseName": "done",
  "totalTime": 2000,
  "disabled": false,
  "_data": 3
}
```

The 2nd event is the one that occurs when your fade-in-up animation actually completes (because it's reached your final `state` of `'in'`), so in your `animationDone()` method, you can just check the passed-in event object's `toState` property being `'in'`, then you know your animation is complete.